# Testing express middleware that returns next() / next("route")

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, middleware

I created this piece of middleware that will return `next()` when the only parameters for a route are defined by `queryItems`.

I recently found [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) which fakes expresses `req` and `res` objects. However it does not fake `next`. I was wondering how that should be done? Below I have an example of me opening up the `next` callback and defining my `expect` statement within it.

```
middleware.hasOnlyQuery = function(queryItems){
  return function(req, res, next){
    if(typeof queryItems == "string") queryItems = [queryItems]
    if(_.hasOnly(req.query, queryItems)) return next()
    return next("route")
  }
}
```

Here's the test.

```
it("should only have shop query", function(done){
  var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      query: {
        foo: "bar"
      }
  });
  var res = httpMocks.createResponse()
  var fn = middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo"])(req, res, function(err){
    expect(err).to.equal()
    return done()
  })
})

it("should not only have shop query", function(done){
  var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      query: {
        foo: "bar",
        bar: "foo"
      }
  });
  var res = httpMocks.createResponse()
  var fn = middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo"])(req, res, function(err){
    expect(err).to.equal("route")
    return done()
  })
})
```

Is this the proper way to do this? Is there any way to make this simpler / easier, perhaps converting it to a promise so I can use chai-as-promised?

> Note: [_.hasOnly](https://gist.github.com/reggi/87ee52f3958e96855a0d) is a custom underscore mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for tests like these:

```
// first test
...
var res = httpMocks.createResponse()
var spy = sinon.spy();
middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo"])(req, res, spy);
expect(spy.calledWithExactly()).to.be.true;

// second test
...
expect(spy.calledWithExactly('route')).to.be.true;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this smoother is to create the three kinds of responses `next can have.

```
function nextNormal(done){
  return function(err){
    expect(err).to.equal(undefined)
    return done()
  }
}

function nextRoute(done){
  return function(err){
    expect(err).to.equal("route")
    return done()
  }
}

function nextError(done){
  return function(err){
    expect(err).to.be.an('object')
    return done()
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in one line

```
middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo", "bar"])(req, res, nextNormal(done))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the middleware to a promise to use with [`express-promise-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router).

```
middleware.hasOnlyQuery = function(queryItems){
  return function(req, res){
    if(typeof queryItems == "string") queryItems = [queryItems]
    if(_.hasOnly(req.query, queryItems)) return Promise.resolve('next')
    return Promise.resolve('route')
  }
}
```

The new test using [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) and [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird):

```
it("should fire correct next callback", function(done){
  Promise.all([
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo"])(reqFoo, res).should.eventually.equal("next"),
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo", "bar"])(reqFoo, res).should.eventually.equal("route"),
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo", "alpha"])(reqFoo, res).should.eventually.equal("route"),
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo"])(reqFooBar, res).should.eventually.equal("route"),
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo", "bar"])(reqFooBar, res).should.eventually.equal("next"),
    middleware.hasOnlyQuery(["foo", "alpha"])(reqFooBar, res).should.eventually.equal("route")
  ]).then(function(){
    done()
  })
})
```